# Syntax of require in the ClojureScript REPL

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This is certainly trivial, but I could not find it anywhere. I am trying to start fiddling with ClojureScript. I was able to get to a ClojureScript REPL with [ClojureScript One](http://clojurescriptone.com/).

I can connect with a browser and execute some simple DOM queries and manipulations there. Now I would like to start saving some useful functions into modules and load them as needed. This is where I get stuck.

If I try something like

```
(require 'project.dom)
```

I get the exception `FileNotFoundException Could not locate project/dom__init.class or project/dom.clj on classpath`. I indeed have only `project/dom.cljs`, as I saw all ClojureScript files in the example use this extension.

If I try to rename it to `project.clj`, I get a complaint about the missing namespace `js`. Of course I use that namespace quite a lot in the module.

> What is the proper way to write a simple ClojureScript file that can work with the browser, and load it from the REPL? Anything that will make able to run this simple example will do:

```
(ns ^{:doc "A module for selecting elements from the DOM."}
  project.dom)

(defn get
  [selector]
  (.querySelectorAll js/document selector))
```

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that

```
(load-namespace 'project.dom)
```

works, but `require` is not implemented yet

Comment: I believe this answer is not up to date, currently you can use require for clojurescript files.